# java int toString() error

Tags: java, string

Hey I am writing a program that calculates the words, sentences, vowels, characters..etc of a textfile. I want to use a toString() to concatenate all the classes and the end and return them in the format: {filename}: {character count}c {vowel count}v {word count}w {line count}l {sentence count}s. I am having trouble with the int classes. Ex `(charCount.toString())'c'` + .... Here is my code so far. Thanks

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class TextFileAnalyzer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TextFileAnalyzer mytfa = new TextFileAnalyzer("/Users/patrickmro/Desktop/text.txt");
            System.out.println(mytfa.getCharCount());
            System.out.println(mytfa.getSentenceCount());
            System.out.println(mytfa.getLineCount());
            System.out.println(mytfa.getVowelCount());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }


    }

  // You'll probably want some private fields
    private java.lang.String filePath; 
    private int sentenceCount; 
    private int wordCount; 
    private int charCount;
    private int lineCount; 
    private int vowelCount; 
    private java.lang.String textString;
  /**
   * Constructs a new TextFileAnalyzer that reads from the given file. All file
   * I/O is complete once this constructor returns.
   * @param filePath a path to the file
   * @throws Exception if any errors are generated by the Java API while reading
   *           from the file
   */
  public TextFileAnalyzer(String filePath) throws Exception {
    // This is your job...
      this.filePath = filePath; 
      charCount = 0;
      int prevChar = -1;
      FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(filePath);
      for(int c = input.read(); c != -1 ; c = input.read()) {
          charCount++; 
          if (c == '.' && prevChar != '.') {
              sentenceCount++;
          }
          if(c == '\n') {
              lineCount++;
          }
          if(Character.isWhitespace(c) && (prevChar != -1 || !Character.isWhitespace(prevChar) )) {
              wordCount++;
          } 
          prevChar = c; 
          if(c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I'|| c == 'O' || c == 'U') {
              vowelCount++;
          }
          if(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i'|| c == 'o' || c == 'u') {
              vowelCount++;
          }

      }

      lineCount++;
      input.close(); 
  }


  /**
   * Returns the number of single-byte characters in the file, including
   * whitespace.
   * 
   * @return the number of characters in the file
   */
   public java.lang.String getfilePath() {
     return this.filePath; 
     }

  public int getSentenceCount() {
      return  sentenceCount ; 
  }
  public int getWordCount() {
      return wordCount  ; 
  }

  public int getCharCount() {
      return charCount ; 
  }

  public int getLineCount() {
      return lineCount ;
  }

  public int getVowelCount() {
      return vowelCount;
  }
  public java.lang.String toString() {

     // {filename}: {character count}c {vowel count}v {word count}w {line count}l {sentence count}s
      return (this.getfilePath())':' + (sentenceCount.toString())'s' + (wordCount.toString())'w';

  }

}
```

Comment: You have an extra `return` in your `toString()` method.

Comment: Yeah but thats not the issue

Comment: As an aside, why are you fully qualifying `String` as `java.lang.String`?  There's no reason to do this unless you've defined your own class called `String` (which you should never, ever do).

Comment: Well, you haven't mentioned what the issue is, so I'm just mentioning whatever I see, and since the title of your question talks about `toString()`...

Comment: Yeah..i took it out. Anyways how can I get my output in the correct format using toString()? {filename}: {character count}c {vowel count}v {word count}w {line count}l {sentence count}s

Comment: Please mention the explicit error in your post, not just an abbreviated form of the error in the title.  Also please post only the relevant code.

Comment: My mistake..I think it is pretty straightforward what I was asking...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Don't mangle the question, that will only net you more downvotes and possibly can help to lead to a question ban. I rolled it back. If you want to get rid of downvotes, consider improving the question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easier one:** change this methods as follows and it will work (due to string concatenation, during which non-Strings are automatically converted to strings.

```
public java.lang.String toString() {
   return this.getfilePath() + ":" + sentenceCount + "s" + wordCount + "w";
}
```

**Alternatively**, replace `int` (which is the primitive data type for integers and hence does not have methods like `toString()`) with `Integer` (which is a Java class for integers, wrapping the primitive `int` inside it and since it is a class, it has methods like `toString()`) everywhere in your code and you would be good.

For example replace:

```
private int sentenceCount;
```

with:

```
private Integer sentenceCount;
```

Also change the return types of the methods from `int` to `Integer`.

Comment: The easier one returns the count but does not add the `c` or `s` after the charCount or sentenceCount.

Comment: Did you try it? Did you just copy my code as it is or enhanced it to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 1):

int is a primitive type in Java and as such has no methods associated with it. However you do not need to use a `toString()` this should work fine 
`return this.getfilePath() +':' + sentenceCount + 's' + wordCount + 'w';`